# Unfortunately app has stopped After adding an image on the splash.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I've edited the splash.xml file I get the "Unfortunately app has stopped" error when i try to run the app.

There was 2 images on this splash.xml file before I've edit it (when the app was working)

- Firstly I've added my new image to the drawable folder (where the first 2 image are)
- and then I've used the Eclipse graphical layout to delete the 2 images and to add my new image
- then I've saved the file and I had cleaned the project then I've run it and I've get the error

I've tried to re-run Eclipse and the emulator but the same problem

Here is the original splash.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/main_bg"
android:gravity="center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="180.0dip"
    android:layout_height="180.0dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/iconmain" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="180.0dip"
    android:layout_height="105.0dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14.0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/title" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the modified version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/main_bg"
android:gravity="center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/applogofull"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the LogCat:

```
    10-30 06:11:11.840: I/art(1961): Debugger is active
10-30 06:11:11.999: I/System.out(1961): Debugger has connected
10-30 06:11:11.999: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:12.203: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:12.403: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:12.603: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:12.803: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:13.004: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:13.204: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:13.404: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:13.605: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:13.805: I/System.out(1961): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-30 06:11:14.006: I/System.out(1961): debugger has settled (1485)
10-30 06:11:14.554: I/art(1961): Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1724(90KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 22MB/30MB, paused 289us total 37.744ms
10-30 06:11:14.560: I/art(1961): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 65(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 22MB/36MB, paused 491us total 5.432ms
10-30 06:11:14.569: I/art(1961): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 22MB/36MB, paused 402us total 9.377ms
10-30 06:11:14.570: I/art(1961): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 462MB allocation
10-30 06:11:14.582: I/art(1961): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 22MB/36MB, paused 2.325ms total 12.381ms
10-30 06:11:14.582: E/art(1961): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 485258948 byte allocation with 15447336 free bytes and 73MB until OOM"
10-30 06:11:14.600: I/art(1961): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 22MB/36MB, paused 1.374ms total 10.202ms
10-30 06:11:14.600: I/art(1961): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 462MB allocation
10-30 06:11:14.609: I/art(1961): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 22MB/36MB, paused 788us total 8.989ms
10-30 06:11:14.610: E/art(1961): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 485258948 byte allocation with 15447336 free bytes and 73MB until OOM"
10-30 06:11:14.610: D/skia(1961): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
10-30 06:11:14.613: D/AndroidRuntime(1961): Shutting down VM
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): Process: com.AbdellahASKI.SoundQuiz, PID: 1961
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.AbdellahASKI.SoundQuiz/com.AbdellahASKI.SoundQuiz.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.AbdellahASKI.SoundQuiz.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:20)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     ... 10 more
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     ... 23 more
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 485258948 byte allocation with 15447336 free bytes and 73MB until OOM
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
10-30 06:11:14.619: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     ... 26 more
```

Thanks guys for the help but when i optimized the Image and I tried to run the app I get another error on the console (the last line is red):

```
[2015-10-30 13:50:45 - SoundQuiz] Dx Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded 
[2015-10-30 13:50:45 - SoundQuiz] Dx 1 error; aborting 
[2015-10-30 13:50:45 - SoundQuiz] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Comment: Post logcat when you say error or unfortunately stopped!!

Comment: Post the crash log along with the code which uses the `splash.xml`.

Comment: Now show us your java code. By the way, your package name is wrong. The com.AbdellahASKI part needs to be all lowercase like this: com.abdellahaski And you should really be providing us the logcat when you're running the application, not debugging it. The debugger could be interfering with the code. Please clear your current logcat and rerun the app. Then post your logcat again.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thanks for the advice As I said I'm new to the android development 
About the java file Is it the SplashActivity.java file ?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk i think starting package name with small alphabet, its just the convention not a compulsion

Comment: @KaranMer, It could be, but I wouldn't take the risk. Once signed and published on Google Play, the package name can not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You are exceding the memory limit when loading the image. Maybe is too big.

there could be different approaches:

1. check the filesize. maybe you can actually optimize the image.
2. If you are running the app in the emulator, increase the Ram of virtual Device to something big enough, 1 or 2gb or so.
3. Tell the system that the app will require more memory, edit the manifest to add  `android:largeHeap="true"` in   `application`

   ```
    <application 
     ...
    android:largeHeap="true" >
   ```

Comment: Thanks Carlos I've optimized the image but when I try to run I get this Message on the console:
    [2015-10-30 13:50:45 - SoundQuiz] Dx Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    [2015-10-30 13:50:45 - SoundQuiz] Dx 1 error; aborting
    [2015-10-30 13:50:45 - SoundQuiz] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Answer (score 0):

The image you added in the drawable is too big to allocate the memory in the emulator that is why you are get the OutOfmemory error because the RAM size is not enough to handle the image,you can resize the image by reducing its size and resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for your help but when i optimized the Image and I tried to run the app I get another error on the console see the question again I've edited it

Comment: what file extension you are using, use png and jpeg and re-size the image to around 600 x 600 based on your requirements

Comment: I'm using just .png and all images sizes are under 600x600
Now I've restore the originale splash screen whith the default images and I'm still getting this error